# Dimension of Hyperplane

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Why the dimension of a of `N` dimensional space `hyperplane` is `N-1`?

Is there a mathematical proof of it?

Comment: What's your definition of hyperplane?

Comment: The definition says 'A hyperplane of an n-dimensional space is a flat subset with dimension n − 1.'

Comment: Right - it's just part of the definition of the word hyperplane.

Answer (score 2):

There is no proof, since it's part of the definition: A hyperplane is defined as an $(n-1)$-dimensional flat.